# Referential integrity

Tags: sql

which method should one follow  to drop master table if its primary key is referenced by a foriegn key in some other table?

i know about on delete cascade, is there any other way?  which is the best practice

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This DDL statement will blow away a table, dropping any foreign keys which reference it.

```
drop table your_master_table cascade constraints
/
```

**edit**

The above syntax works in Oracle and SQL Server.  If you get a syntax error you will need to consult the SQL reference for your flavour of database.